# django request.session.user in template

Tags: python, django, session

I am trying to use a custom User model and upon sign_in, I want to redirect the user to the homepage with the current user's information in the session. I ran the app in debug mode  and checked session information in chrome dev tools. It looks like everything is set as required, but the template code is not able to read session information correctly

**models.py**

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email=models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, blank=True)
    .....
```

**views.py**

```
def sign_in(request):
    user=None
    # import pdb; pdb.set_trace();
    if request.method=='POST':
        form=SigninForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            results=User.objects.filter(email=form.cleaned_data['email'])
            if len(results) == 1:
                if results[0].check_password(form.cleaned_data['password']):
                    request.session['user'] = results[0].pk
                    request.user=results[0]
                    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
                else:
                .........
```

**Template**

```
    {% if user %} <!-- I have also tried request.session.user !>
      <li><a href="{% url 'sign_out' %}">Logout</a></li>
    {% else %}
      <li><a href="{% url 'sign_in' %}">Login</a></li>
      <li><a href="{% url 'register' %}">Register</a></li>
    {% endif %}
```

**Debug session**.

```
>>> from django.test import Client
>>> resp=Client().post('/sign_in/',{'email':'another@user.com','password':'anotherpassword2'})
> .../account/views.py(10)sign_in()
-> if request.method=='POST':
...
-> if len(results) == 1:
(Pdb) n
> .../account/views.py(15)sign_in()
-> if results[0].check_password(form.cleaned_data['password']):
(Pdb) n
> .../account/views.py(16)sign_in()
-> request.session['user'] = results[0].pk
(Pdb) n
> .../account/views.py(17)sign_in()
-> request.user=results[0]
(Pdb) n
> .../account/views.py(18)sign_in()
-> return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
(Pdb) request.session.user
*** AttributeError: 'SessionStore' object has no attribute 'user'
(Pdb) request.session['user']
9
(Pdb) user
(Pdb)
```

I also noticed that the session has some information, and this is what I get when I decode the info.

```
>>> from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session
>>> sess = Session.objects.get(pk='XXXX')
>>> print(sess.session_data)
.....
>>> print(sess.get_decoded())
{u'_auth_user_hash': u'XXXXX', u'_auth_user_backend': u'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend', u'_auth_user_id': 1, u'user': 9}

>>> from django_project import settings
>>> settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL
'account.User'
```

Comment: have you set the [AUTH_USER_MODEL in your settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model) so that django knows that you have substituted your user model?

Comment: It looks like your code is working correctly. In your debug session, you can see `request.session['user']` returns `9`. Could you elaborate more as to what you think is wrong?

Comment: @xblitz - I made the changes, but the result is the same

Comment: @DerekKwok - My homepage template is not recognizing that the user is signed in, so I see "sign in/register" options instead of sign out

Comment: I edited the question to add some more info. looks like the session data is being set, but reading it in the template isn't somehow working

Comment: Can you post your view for rendering your homepage?

Comment: Why are you doing this rather than using the built-in login functions? They work well with custom user models.

Comment: @Daniel - My impression was that once I set the user in the session, I can use it without passing it to each template, so I did not try the built-in login functions. WIll try them now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`request.session` usually doesn't have a `user` object - double check by running `p request.session.keys()` in `Pdb`.

Depending on how you render your template* you can access the user via `{% request.user %}`.

`{% user %}` wont work, unless you specifically pass `user` to the template.

*https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#render

**Example:**

*in view:*

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def foo(request):
    #...stuff
    return render(request, 'index.html', {})
```

*in template*

```
{% request.user %}
```

**or**

*in view:*

```
def foo(request):
    #...stuff
    user = request.user
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'user':user})
```

*in template*

```
{% user %}
```

**Edit**

If you want to check to see if the user is logged in you should use `{% if user.is_authenticated %}` in your template. Not `{% if user %}`

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_authenticated

Comment: Thanks Ben. This makes sense and it worked. However, it now only works for the index page. All the other pages still show the "sign-in" link, even though the user is already logged in.

Comment: I added an edit that will solve the problem. Also, make sure all other pages are being rendered in the same manner.

Comment: Thanks Ben. I went through django auth and the functions for login and authenticate. Since I am using a custom model, I am now implementing these functions and a User Manager before I check is_authenticated. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example